# call constructor multiple times

Tags: c++, constructor, daemon

Debugging an insane system.
The constructor of a class is called multiple times, and their memory address are the same. Does this mean they are the same object? 
Create object @ 0xa3d82a0
Create object @ 0xa3d82a0
Create object @ 0xa3d82a0

I also see xxxx is a daemon.
What does daemon mean?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably the address of the constructor in memory (unsure though)

Answer (score 1):

It could just mean that the constructor is being kept in the same block of memory (locality of reference and all that) to save memory.

As for the second part of the question, to quote: "A daemon (or service) is a background process that is designed to run autonomously,with little or not user intervention."

[Taken from here](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html) (don't bother with any of the links on the page, they all seem to be dead. Just botched anchor tags, though).

Comment: But does this mean that the values of the variables in the class are the same for all the objects?

Comment: Well, that depends on the constructor. If it's just a default constructor without any parameters, then by definition yes. But if it takes in parameters, then it will likely have been passed the value/memory location of the parameters when the call was made and used those values in each operation.

What the call is doing is referencing the memory location of the set of instructions (in assembly or similar) which are doing the declaration of the objects. It probably goes about its business every time it's called, then saves the new object in free memory and returns to the stack.

Comment: sorry, still a little confusion. NO parameter in the constructor. But if one object gives some pointers in the class some value, and the other objects reference the pointers, will they get the same value as  the first object?

Comment: No. What I'm trying to say is that the set of instructions for creating an object might be in a static spot of memory (0xa3d82a0), but that does not mean that all the objects are the same. They are (should be) separate instances at separate memory locations. So later access of the objects should be referencing separate objects.

Comment: I see.. Thanks! That's what I want to avoid. Is there any way to make them to use some variables? For example, I want to define some pointers and copy some contents for them. Is there an easy way only to do once, rather than for each object?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll have to think about it. In any case, this seems like a different question than the original. Try making a new post for that question, maybe someone else can help you faster.

Comment: I indeed post another question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346339/pass-pointers-to-a-class-but-not-in-constructor-parameters bizarre question..

Comment: Try rewording that post. Add some code, as well, for context. As it stands, the question is far too vague and can't be properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same object. An object can only be constructed once. The behavior you see is not unlikely, for example if many objects are being allocated on the stack in a loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() { cout << "Creat" << this << endl; }
};

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        A a;
    }
}
```

Here 'a' will be constructed in the same location over an over again, printing something like:

```
Creat0xbfcd871f
Creat0xbfcd871f
Creat0xbfcd871f
Creat0xbfcd871f
Creat0xbfcd871f
```

Comment: Ah... i see.. I never knew this before. Thanks.